# How to compare addresses in Excel

Tags: excel

How can I compare addresses in Excel? When road and street are abbreviated into Rd and St excel doesnt recognize these as being the same and thus says they're not. In the example below how can I get excel to only say that row 2 is wrong as it doesn't have Yamato but that the first and last ones are fine?

```
14255 49th St. North    14255 49th St N Ste 301
1001 Yamato Rd.         1001 NW 51st St Ste 200
2031 Randolph Road      2031 Randolph Rd
```

Comment: Look into `Fuzzy Lookup` there is an add on you can find that will help in this.

Comment: better answer than I was going to give.

Comment: [HERE](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011) is a link to microsoft's version.

Comment: lol this is @brayheart who deleted his [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37469312/vba-instr-compared-values-not-finding-values#37469312) Edit: fyi, OP claims today was first time noticing my answer for his other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37034937/vba-how-to-delete-rows-when-value-of-column-x-does-not-match-value-of-column-y/37039202#37039202) when I specifically pinged by handle.

Comment: @findwindow I swear it was, I'm not sure why you think I'm not telling the truth. I probably saw your post and didnt respond as I had gone another route, I didn't mean to offend you.. In any case fuzzy lookup looks like it should work

Comment: Because you got pinged twice. And now you do the shady thing of creating new account to ask same question XD Just because I won't help you, doesn't mean rest of SO won't. No need to delete question and create new account.